# How to aggreagte specific column on time

Tags: python, dataframe, aggregate

I have a dataframe

```
                              dt  ... compare
0      2021-03-19 14:59:49+00:00  ...       1
1      2021-03-19 14:59:51+00:00  ...       0
2      2021-03-19 14:59:51+00:00  ...       0
3      2021-03-19 14:59:51+00:00  ...       1
4      2021-03-19 14:59:52+00:00  ...       0
```

I want to aggregate dt daily
here is what i tried

```
aggregate_compare = pd.DataFrame(comments)
aggregate_compare['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(aggregate_compare['dt'])
daily_summary = aggregate_compare.compare.resample('D', on='dt').sum()
```

but it gives an error
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'resample'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
aggregate_compare = pd.DataFrame(comments)
aggregate_compare['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(aggregate_compare['dt'])
daily_summary = aggregate_compare.resample('D', on='dt').sum() # .mean()
print(daily_summary)
```

**EDIT**

Here you will get counts of each day observation

**Method 1**

```
aggregate_compare = pd.DataFrame(comments)
f = dict(compare='sum', dt='count')
aggregate_compare['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(aggregate_compare['dt'])
g = pd.Grouper(key = 'dt', freq = 'd')
daily_summary = aggregate_compare.groupby(g).agg(f)
```

**Method 2**

```
aggregate_compare = pd.DataFrame(comments)
aggregate_compare['counts'] = 1
aggregate_compare['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(aggregate_compare['dt'])
daily_summary = aggregate_compare.resample('D', on='dt').sum()
print(daily_summary)
```

**Method 3**

```
aggregate_compare = pd.DataFrame(comments)
aggregate_compare['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(aggregate_compare['dt'])
daily_summary = aggregate_compare.groupby("dt").mean()
print(daily_summary)
```

**O/P** - Sample data i created

```
                       compare  counts
dt      
2021-03-18 00:00:00+00:00   5   4
2021-03-19 00:00:00+00:00   3   3
```

Documentation as follows https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html

Comment: Also, do you know how to get values that were aggregated between each day because I might want to divide aggregated value by the number of rows to get ratio. Thank you

Comment: Do you meant divide by day count

Comment: so lets say for day one i have 20 observations and the sum is 5 so i want to divide 5/20 for day 2 i have 10 observations and sum 7 so 7/10